# Compute the norm of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $T$ be a nonzero bounded linear operator in $B(H)$, where $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. If the norm of $T$ is known, how to compute the norm $\|I–T\|$,where $I$ is the identity operator.

Comment: Just knowing the norm of $T$ does not allow you to compute the norm of $I-T$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. You have the estimate
$$
0\leq\|I-T\|\leq\|I\|+\|T\|,
$$
and both inequalities can be made sharp: take $T=I$ for the first one, and $T=-I$ for the second one; in both cases, $\|T\|=1$.

Comment: That's too vague of a question. If your operator is given explicitly in some sense, it might be possible to calculate the spectrum or find an inverse explicitly. In other cases you are given some property that allows you to determine invertibility. There's no general answer.